# How to split this kind of string in C#

Tags: c#, .net, split

Well, i have a file with this info:

> 04/12/2012      06/12/2012   XX123410116000020000118 XEPLATINOXE XX XXXEXX XXXX PLATINOX  XX                      $     131.07

this is a full line, into the file I have got 10 lines more like this, I want to use split in C# to get the next result:

```
 Line[0]= 04/12/2012
 Line[1]= 06/12/2012
 Line[2]= XX123410116000020000118
 Line[3]= XEPLATINOXE XX XXXEXX XXXX PLATINOX  XX
 Line[4]= $     131.07
```

I try to do this but doesn't work, please help me.

Thanks.

Bless!

Comment: How consistent is it?  Is it always four strings followed by a dollar amount?  Do you need the dollar sign in the final string?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, Someone post this answer and it works for me!

```
String[] array1 = file_[count + 19].Split(new[] { " " }, 4,StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
```

I don´t need to split the last array, in this case:

```
array[3]
```

because its fine for me this format:

> XEPLATINOXE XX XXXEXX XXXX PLATINOX XX            $         131.07

thanks a lot!

Bless!

Answer (score 1):

I'm sure someone will suggest a fancy RegEx but here's a way to do it without one:

```
string source = "04/12/2012 06/12/2012 XX123410116000020000118 XEPLATINOXE XX XXXEXX XXXX PLATINOX XX $ 131.07";
string[] split1 = source.Split('$');
string[] split2 = split1[0].Split(new char[] {' '},4);  // limit to 4 results
string lines = split2.Concat(new [] {split1[1]});
```

Answer (score 0):

04/12/2012 06/12/2012 XX123410116000020000118 XEPLATINOXE XX XXXEXX XXXX PLATINOX XX $ 131.07

can get parsed out with a regex by using grouping braces, but to get a really reliable result, we'd need to know what parts of your record are consistent.

I'm going to assume the third item never has whitespace, and the fifth item always starts with a $

```
using System;
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;

class Program
{
    static void Main()
    {
        // First we see the input string.
        string input = "04/12/2012 06/12/2012 XX123410116000020000118 XEPLATINOXE XX XXXEXX XXXX PLATINOX XX $ 131.07";

        // Here we call Regex.Match.
        Match match = Regex.Match(input, @"^(\d\d\/\d\d\/\d{4}) (\d\d\/\d\d\/\d{4}) (\S+) ([^\$]+) (\$.+)$");

        // Here we check the Match instance.
        if (match.Success)
        {
            // Your results are stored in  match.Groups[1].Value, match.Groups[2].Value, match.Groups[3].Value, 
            //      match.Groups[4].Value, and match.Groups[5].Value, so now you can do whatever with them
            Console.WriteLine(match.Groups[5].ToString());
            Console.ReadKey();
        }
    }
}
```

Some useful links:

- http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms228595%28v=vs.80%29.aspx
- http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/az24scfc.aspx